# How to replace any double quotes with two double quotes inside a batch variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm trying to make a program that types out the clipboard, word by word. So far, I have done everything except work out how to escape the double quote in the VBS file. To do this, I need another double quote. This is my code as of now:

```
@echo off & setlocal & cd "%temp%" & paste > x.txt
for /f "delims=" %%A in (x.txt) do set X=%%A & timeout /t 4 /nobreak
:loop
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%X%") do (
set "Y=%%A" & set X=%%B
)
set Z=%Y:^"=^"^"%
echo CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SendKeys "%Z% " > x.vbs
start /wait x.vbs & if defined Y (set "Y=" & goto :loop) & pause
```

I am obviously doing something wrong on this line:

```
set Z=%Y:^"=^"^"%
```

Comment: you should be able to work without a temp file with `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('paste') do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to escape the quotes:

```
set z="a--b"
echo %z:"=""%
```